# case results in used in same query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

I am trying to do something similar to this, but not sure how to do this in a sql query. I first create the column and then want to drop the column since its a calculated column and I was always learn not to use calculated columns in table

```
Alter table baseSupple add Buys int null
GO
select com.YrAmount, Buys = 
case when b.BaseAmount is null
   then com.Amount+ com.BaseAmount+ com.Amount1
   when b.BaseAmount is not null
   then com.Amount+ com.Amount1+ b.BaseAmount 
END, Sum(b.Buys - com.Tng) as Fy11, Sum(b.Buys - com.Tng - com.Tng) as Fy12  from baseSupple as b inner join comSupple as com on com.id = b.id
GO
Alter table baseSupple drop Buys
```

I thought I can do this with a case statement but it gives me an error because Invalid column name is not recognized since its in the same statement. I assuming if I can get this to work I can copy and paste the sql for a report in a report.rdl file I am new to sql server report server so not sure if this is the right approach to generate this type of report in sql server business intelligence development studio

Comment: Why would you create, fill and then drop a column again in the same query?? If you don't need that data in the table - can't you just create a temporary table or a table variable to hold that data while you need it, instead of altering your "real" table twice??

Comment: well I actually never heard of a table variable. I can try to look into that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this seems to be the basis for a report you want to run, I would probably create a view over your base table:

```
-- create a view as the data source for your report
CREATE VIEW dbo.baseSuppleView AS
  -- create a CTE to determine the "Buys" column
  WITH BuysCTE AS
  (
      SELECT 
          com.YrAmount,
          com.Tng,
          Buys = CASE 
                    WHEN b.BaseAmount IS NULL
                       THEN com.Amount + com.BaseAmount + com.Amount1
                    ELSE
                      com.Amount + com.Amount1 + b.BaseAmount 
                 END 
      FROM dbo.baseSupple AS b 
      INNER JOIN dbo.comSupple AS com ON com.id = b.id
  )
  SELECT   -- select from that CTE - now defined, you can use the "Buys" column
      YrAmount, 
      Buys, 
      SUM(Buys - Tng) AS Fy11, 
      SUM(Buys - 2 * Tng) AS Fy12  
  FROM BuysCTE
  GROUP BY YrAmount, Buys  -- when you have SUM(....), you need GROUP BY(....)
```

and then just use this **view** as the source for your report.

Since the computation of that column is done in the view definition, your base table and its performance is in no way affected by this computed column, and you don't have to constantly create and drop columns in your table....

Comment: column name Buys would still be unrecognizable in this query though

Comment: @Jake: true - you'd have to have a subquery that defines the `Buys` column and then build a second select on top of that ... let me update my post...

Comment: I like the idea of using the CTE, but why use a view? this report will not be changed or altered with parameters?

Comment: @Jake: I was just assuming that the report might need a view or table as the data source - that's why I assumed creating a view might be a good idea. But if that's not the case, if you can have a SQL statement itself as the data source, then by all means - just use the CTE and the following SELECT !

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why you need the alter tables..

```
Select yrAmount, SUM(Buys-tng) as FY11, Sum(buys-tng-tng) as FY12
FROM (
select com.YrAmount, 
case when b.BaseAmount is null
  then com.Amount+ com.BaseAmount+ com.Amount1
  when b.BaseAmount is not null
  then com.Amount+ com.Amount1+ b.BaseAmount END as buys
FROM baseSupple b
INNER JOIN comSupple com 
 on com.id = b.id) A
```

EDITED: forgot to pull buys out of subquery.

Comment: how would this work? buys would be unrecognizable in the subquery as well as the main query?

Answer (score 0):

No need of any DDL changes to get your required calculations. I guess the below one should work.

```
`SELECT com.YrAmount, 
     CASE when b.BaseAmount is null
        then com.Amount+ com.BaseAmount+ com.Amount1
        when b.BaseAmount is not null
        then com.Amount+ com.Amount1+ b.BaseAmount 
     END as Buys,
     Sum(b.Buys - com.Tng) as Fy11, 
     Sum(b.Buys - com.Tng - com.Tng) as Fy12
FROM baseSupple as b inner join comSupple as com
   on com.id = b.id
GO`
```

Regards,
Venk